# Using ttmath in CMake project compiled with the Visual Studio 2013 64-bit compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, qt-creator, linker-errors

When including the header

```
#include "ttmath/ttmath.h"
```

as described on [ttmath's web page](http://www.ttmath.org/samples) (where the library is contained in the folder `ttmath` inside the project folder), I get the a number of compiler errors like the following:

```
main.cpp.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ttmath_adc_x64 referenced in function "public: unsigned __int64 __cdecl ttmath::UInt<28>::Add(class ttmath::UInt<28> const &,unsigned __int64)" (?Add@?$UInt@$0BM@@ttmath@@QEAA_KAEBV12@_K@Z)
```

I'm using QT Creator 3.3.1, which generated the `CMakeLists.txt` file

```
project(my_project)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [here](http://www.ttmath.org/forum/how_to_compile_with_visual_studio_2010_64-bit), the problem is that Visual Studio 64 bit doesn't support inlining of the assembly code file `ttmathuint_x86_64_msvc.asm`. The options therefore are

1. Disable assembly by adding

   ```
   #define TTMATH_NOASM 1
   ```

   before including `ttmath.h`. This will cost about a factor of two in performance.
2. Assemble and include the file manually:

   - Run the command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\ml64.exe" /c ttmathuint_x86_64_msvc.asm` (inside the `ttmath` folder).
   - Include the object file in compilation by replacing the last line in `CMakeLists.txt` with

     `add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST} ttmath/ttmathuint_x86_64_msvc.obj)`

Comment: For anyone using the VS IDE instead of CMake: you can simply drag the .obj file into the source folder in the Solution Explorer in VS after running the assembler as above. Also, my *ml64.exe* was located at *"%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\Hostx64\x64\"* for VS2017, which required editing the included *win64_assemble.bat* file. (Recommend Notepad++ or similar to edit on Windows, since the included file uses POSIX linefeeds and Notepad doesn't like them.)